# Returning records that have a set of related tags

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables, assignments and Assignment_tags

```
ASSIGNMENTS
-----------
ASSIGNMENTID     int
ASSIGNMENTNAME   nvarchar(50)

ASSIGNMENT_TAGS
---------------
TAGID            int
ASSIGNMENTID     int
TAGNAME          nvarchar(50)
```

Each assignment can have multiple tags.

I need a SQL query to return assignments for a given tag list.  I need those assignments to have all those tags.

```
ASSIGNMENTS Table
-----------------
ASSIGNMENTID        ASSIGNMENTNAME
1                   Assignment 1
2                   Assignment 2
3                   Assignment 3

ASSIGNMENT_TAGS Table
---------------------
TAGID               ASSIGNMENTID       TAGNAME
1                   1                  Some Tag
2                   2                  Some Tag
3                   1                  Another Tag
4                   3                  A Different Tag
5                   2                  A Different Tag
```

If I supplied 'Some Tag,Another Tag' as a comma delimited tag list as an input parameter to a stored procedure, I would expect the query to return ASSIGNMENTID 1 as this assignment has both tags.

I'm sure this is easy, but my brain does not seem to be working today.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Design-wise, your description looks like you should have 3 tables instead of 2: ASSIGNMENTS, TAGS and ASSIGNMENT_TAGS, with the TAGNAME in the tags table table instead of instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I suggest having this usefull function that converts an anychar-delimited-list string into a table.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Split]
(
@String NVARCHAR(4000),
@Delimiter NCHAR(1)
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS

RETURN
(
    WITH Split(stpos,endpos)
    AS(
        SELECT 0 AS stpos, CHARINDEX(@Delimiter,@String) AS endpos
        UNION ALL
        SELECT endpos+1, CHARINDEX(@Delimiter,@String,endpos+1)
            FROM Split
            WHERE endpos > 0
    )
    SELECT 'ID_Split' = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)),
        'Data' = RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@String,stpos,COALESCE(NULLIF(endpos,0),LEN(@String)+1)-stpos)))
    FROM Split
)
GO
```

Having this function you can know which ASSINGMENTSID is not related at least with one tag of the list.

```
DECLARE @Comma_delimited_tag_list VARCHAR(500) = 'Some Tag,Another Tag'
DECLARE @Delimiter VARCHAR(1) = ','

SELECT
        A.ASSIGNMENTID, B.*, AT.*
    FROM [dbo].[Split](@Comma_delimited_tag_list, @Delimiter) B
        FULL JOIN ASSIGNMENTS A ON 1 = 1
        LEFT JOIN ASSIGNMENT_TAGS AT ON AT.ASSIGNMENTID = A.ASSIGNMENTID AND AT.TAGNAME = B.Data
    WHERE
        AT.ASSIGNMENTID IS NULL
```

Result:

```
ASSIGNMENTID ID_Split             Data        TAGID       ASSIGNMENTID TAGNAME
------------ -------------------- ----------- ----------- ------------ ----------------
2            2                    Another Tag NULL        NULL         NULL
3            1                    Some Tag    NULL        NULL         NULL
3            2                    Another Tag NULL        NULL         NULL
```

Finally knowing this we can know which ASSIGNMENTIDs fit all tags nesting the prev query in the following.

```
DECLARE @Comma_delimited_tag_list VARCHAR(500) = 'Some Tag,Another Tag'
DECLARE @Delimiter VARCHAR(1) = ','

SELECT
        A.*
    FROM ASSIGNMENTS A
        LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT
                    A.ASSIGNMENTID
                FROM [dbo].[Split](@Comma_delimited_tag_list, @Delimiter) B
                    FULL JOIN ASSIGNMENTS A ON 1 = 1
                    LEFT JOIN ASSIGNMENT_TAGS AT ON AT.ASSIGNMENTID = A.ASSIGNMENTID AND AT.TAGNAME = B.Data
                WHERE
                    AT.ASSIGNMENTID IS NULL
        ) B
        ON A.ASSIGNMENTID = B.ASSIGNMENTID
    WHERE
        B.ASSIGNMENTID IS NULL
```

```
ASSIGNMENTID | ASSIGNMENTNAME
------------ | --------------
1            | Assignment 1
```

It works for list with any @Delimiter value.

Hope it's works for you.

Comment: Thanks for your assistance.  This just seems to return every assignment, irrespective of what tags I supply.

Comment: Could you provide a code example?. The latests query I posted worked fine for me.

Comment: @NeilBurton I have updated the answer, it should work now.

Comment: sorry for the late reply.  This works now.  Thanks Ric

Answer (score 0):

Working with comma-delimited lists is painful.  But you can do it:

```
select att.assignmentid
from assignmenttags att
where ',' + @tags + ',' = '%,' + att.tagname + ',%'
group by att.assignmentid
having count(distinct att.tagname) = (length(@tags) - 
                                       length(replace(@tags, ',', '')
                                      ) + 1;
```

This assumes that the input list has only commas that separate the values and there are no duplicate values in the list.